# Umbraco 9 instellisense does not work inside cshtml

Tags: umbraco

I have freshly installed vs 2022 and created Umbraco 9.5.1 project. When I go to generated view, for example Views/test.cshtml and try to see the members of Model, I get nothing:

[image]

I tried setting the following option:

> ```
> "Umbraco": {
>     "CMS": {
>       "ModelsBuilder": {
>         "ModelsMode": "SourceCodeManual",
>         "ModelsDirectory": "~/umbraco/models"
>       },
> ```

But it started giving me the following error:

[image]

How can I enable intellisense in the views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to include all the generated files in you project/solution, as well as the view files. That *should* do it?

Comment: It seems like all generated files I can find are included by default, it is only cshtml views in Views directory? umbraco/Models directory is empty except for ood.flag file.

Comment: If there's an ood.flag file it means the data models are Out Of Date - and that the models need to be generated. That's what the SourceCodeManual setting does. Go to Settings section - Models Builder tab and there should be a button allowing the models to be regenerated (and then included in project if necessary).